# Adding angularjs files from external source to the page

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a project where we need to load an AngularJS app to another website (different server/domains). How is this achieved? Is it a simple  with all the JS and HTML files?

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please use 10 minutes to learn how to make a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the size of your project, it could be slow and heavy to serve it as is.
If you have a lot of static assets like CSS, images etc you may benefit from bundling.
My recommendation is to add [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) build tool to your project, it has **a lot** of minifying and bundling options.
Another useful link about webpack: [webpack when to use and why](http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/)